# Efecto hover dentro de un enlace

Tags: html, css, hover

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;
    color:white;">Opciones</a>
```

Estoy haciendo una firma de mi correo electrónico, la cual solo respeta los estilos colocados en las etiquetas mismas, como se muestra arriba, donde le doy los estilos dentro del mismo enlace, ¡lo que ahora no entiendo es cómo hago la pseudoclase en ella!

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué es lo que te ocurre y qué esperas que ocurra? Imagino que no quieres que salga el subrayado del enlace, ¿cierto?

Comment: Ahhh, ¡ya he entendido! Estás diseñando un HTML para agregar como firma en el envío de mensajes de correo electrónico con un cliente de correo. Siento decirte que no puedes hacer lo que deseas si no es usando la etiqueta `<style>` como te he indicado. Thunderbird te lo permite, pero estoy comprobando la compatibilidad con webmails (que son los más exigentes a la hora de mostrar HTML dentro de un correo).

Answer (score 1):

Algo mas o menos asi seria?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>


<a href="#" style="color:#009933;"

onMouseOver="this.style.cssText='color: #cc0000'" 

onMouseOut="this.style.cssText='color: #009933'"> Enlace </a> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

También podrías ponerle a esa etiqueta una clase un id y en el archivo .css decirle a esa clase o ese id lo que debería de hacer, ejemplo:

```css
#opciones{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#009933;
}
#opciones:hover{
    color:#cc0000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="opciones">Opciones</a>
```

aunque qué es quieres que sea por una etiqueta HMTL, la forma que propongo yo del CSS fuera de tu HTML sería la más ordenada.